# My object cannot be initialized because of the "else if" loop for some reason

Tags: java, object, if-statement, initialization

I'm trying to add three kinds of monsters into an array by initializing my Monster-object based on the modulo. (I'm just a beginner so bear with me).

```
for (int i=0; i<nrofMonsters; i++) {
    Monster m;
    if (i%2==0) { 
        m = new Vampire("Vamp-"+i);
    } else if(i%2==1) {
        m = new Ghost("Ghost-"+i);
    } else if(i%3==2){
        m = new Demon("Demon-"+i);
    }
    monsters.add(m);
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE: variable m might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: there are possible execution paths throughout your code that won't lead to an assignment of a specific value into `m` before it is being accesses in the `monsters.add(m);` statement.

Specifically, there's no final `else` assigning some other value in the `if-else if` chain:

```
if (i%2==0) { 
    m = new Vampire("Vamp-"+i);
} else if(i%2==1) {
    m = new Ghost("Ghost-"+i);
} else if(i%3==2){
    m = new Demon("Demon-"+i);
}
else {
    m = …whatever…; // or, handle this as an error
}
monsters.add(m);
```

Note that the compiler (apparently) isn't smart enough to understand the conditions in `if`s and hence can't tell the `else` part isn't necessary.

---

I *think* you, in fact, wanted something like this:

```
if(i%3==2){
    m = new Demon("Demon-"+i);
} else if (i%2==0) { 
    m = new Vampire("Vamp-"+i);
} else {
    m = new Ghost("Ghost-"+i);
}
```

Comment: @Re-Animator Good. For your next questions: It's really helpful to specify your programming language by tagging your question with the respective tag.

Answer (score 0):

The if else ladder goes from top to bottom.  When you delete based on modulo 2 you can have only 2 outcomes 0  or 1. Therefore you will never reach i%3. You can delete everything based on 3 and you will have 3 outcomes.

As mentioned below I don't believe it is an init issue - can you share the language you are writing on.(And do check the inheritance tree - there can be some nasty mistakes there, when you are a beginner)

Comment: Which is true, but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yea, but there is no way to go to a default else as well, because of the module 2 logic. So the problem might be one of inheritance nature. For instance if the monsters list are not the root class

Comment: That seems a bit off to me. There's no inheritance issue whatsoever. The OP is getting a clear compiler error and wants to understand it *at the first place*. The fact that the OP's program's logic is flawed is second.

Comment: Yes but based on the logic it is not possible to not be initialized - You will aways go either in the Vampire or Ghost init. So I don't believe it is an initialization issue. And the compiler contains the word might

Comment: How can you tell the compiler is able to tell `(i%2==0 || i%2==1)` is *always* `true`? This is a pretty damn hard problem and the language, which *wasn't* (!) specificed by the OP, may not require for a compiler to be *that* smart.

Comment: It's Java! Sorry mate, it's my first question!

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'm' is a local variable .
It is a must that local variables must be initialized.
Else it must it lead to compilation error.

A simple assignment like the below one will resolve the issue:

Monster m = null;

Though the above assignment will lead to a NullPointerException, since the code might not reach any of the 'if' or 'else if' constructs.

Thus it is best to add the 'else' construct to ensure that the code runs successfully.